# Выборка ID с одного склада

Tags: mysqli

Есть таблица product_stock.
В ней id складов и id товаров. Нужно выбрать ID товаров которые входят ТОЛЬКО в определенные id складов, например 49, но этих товаров нету на других складах.

То есть может быть товар с id 1 на складе с id 4,12,49

Может быть товар с id 2 на складе 49 и за этим id не закреплено других складов, кроме 49.

Как мне получить все записи таких товаров, как с id 2 ?

Comment: Извините, но не совсем понимаю как мне должно помочь SUM и COUNT. Можете объяснить подробнее свою мысль и логику? Номера складов определены и мне нужно получить ID товаров, которые входят только в конкретный склад и никакой больше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> мне нужно получить ID товаров, которые входят только в конкретный склад и никакой больше.

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(stock_id) stock_id
FROM product_stock
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT stock_id) = 1
```

Если пара полей `(product_id, stock_id)` в структуре уникальна (имеется уникальный индекс), DISTINCT можно убрать за ненадобностью.

Если нужны товары только для определённого склада - добавить `AND MAX(stock_id) = {номер склада}`, при этом из списка вывода номер склада можно убрать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

```
product_id | store_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 2
3          | 3
```

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(store_id) cnt, MAX(store_id) store 
FROM `product` 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING cnt = 1 AND store IN (1,2)
```

Из выборки группировкой извлекаем те товары, которые:

- находятся только на одном складе `cnt = 1`
- номер склада входит в список требуемых `store in (1,2)`

```
product_id | cnt | store
2          | 1   | 2
```